# JQuery-AJAX post workflow

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

**EDIT**

Forgot a couple of improtant points.

1. I am doing this to eliminate the page from having to refresh and therefore jumping back up to the top of the page.
2. The success function of the ajax function will kick back an entire new div id="comments" to replace the existing one with either an error msg or the new comment with all other below it.

**END EDIT**

I have been trying to this jquery-ajax function under wraps unsuccessfully. I have X number of posts on a page with each having a form for inserting comments under each post. I think I am pretty close and have tried to debug it using firebug, but honestly I don't really know what I am looking at or for in firebug.

All code is below, any help would be much appreciated!

HTML form and structure (because of the repetative forms, I feel I should use the parent jquery selection method, rather than iterating each post-comment partition in my output script)

```
    <div id="content_body_right">
        <div id="activity">
            ....this is the area for each post....
        </div>
        <div id="comments">
            <p class="comments_label">' . $reply_count . ' Comment</p>
            <div id="comment1">
                <div id="comment_user_img">
                    ' . $imgOutputReply . '
                </div>
                <div id="comment_user">
                    <p class="user_text_comment">' . $firstNameReply . ' ' . $lastNameReply . '</p><p class="date_text_comment">' . $date_timeReply . '</p>
                    <p class="message_text_comment">' . $messageReply . '</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="add_comment">
                <form id="formAddComment" action="dashboard.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <div id="add_comment_left">
                    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="75" rows="2">Add a Comment...</textarea> 
                </div>
                <div id="add_comment_right">
                    <input id="userID" name="userID" type="hidden" value="' . $userID . '" />
                    <input id="actID" name="actID" type="hidden" value="' . $actID . '" />
                    <input id="btnComment" name="btnComment" type="submit" value="" title="Add Comment" />
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

OK, now the JQuery markup

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formAddComment").submit( function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                var div_add_comment = form.parent();
                var div_comments = div_add_comment.parent();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    url: "includes/comment.php",
                    success: function(msg){
                        $div_comments.html(msg);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Lastly the external php script (NOTE: I will only post the initial lines where i localize the data feed into php vars.)

```
    if(isset($_POST['actID'])){
        $actID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['actID']);
        $userID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userID']);
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
          ............other processing here...........
    }
```

I am suspicious of my jquery script mostly.

Thanks again,

Comment: Your "html" in the top code block is actually mixed php and html. Not that that's a big deal, but it's a little confusing - giving the actual generated html of a single form would probably be more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery works with selectors.  When you write $(something) something is the selector.  It can be an id, a class name, a variable, html elements.  So instead of

```
$("#formAddComment").submit( function(e) {
```

You could use

```
$(".someclassName").submit( function(e) {
```

just like css, use # for id, . for class.  Just make sure you add the class attribute to your form with the same name.  You could also try

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
```

which should select any form elements.  I think the rest of your function should work fine with this change, since you are using 'this' and parent() instead of any direct references.

Comment: does each form class need to be iterated, or just add a class with the same value in while loop?

Comment: The class can be the same in all forms

Comment: Thanks kgarrigan, got it working this morning, using the class selector rather than the id selector. Lesson learned, for me and other rooks, when repeating an html element on a page from a php loop, use a repeting class and not a repeating id. THANKS AGAIN KGARRIGAN!

Answer (score 1):

I dropped the general structure into a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cori/JsLWq/, and when I submit the form I do indeed get an ajax POST to the non-existant `http://fiddle.jshell.net/cori/JsLWq/show/includes/comment.php` due to the relative ajax url, so that's not the problem as far as I can tell.  What I *do* think is the problem is that you're mixing your variable naming rules.

You start off naming your variables like plain-old javascript objects

```
var form = $(this);
var div_add_comment = form.parent();
var div_comments = div_add_comment.parent();
```

but then in your success handler you switch to the fairly-common `$x` convention, often used to indicate that a variable is a jQuery instance:

```
$div_comments.html(msg);
```

however at that point there is no variable `$div_comments`; only `div_comments`. If you submit the form in http://jsfiddle.net/cori/JsLWq/1/, which has an ajax error handler, and look at your firebug console, you'll see that you get a ReferenceError because `$div_comments` is undefined.

**EDIT**

Incorporating kgarrigan's suggestions, if in your php you loop over the forms you want to create, and keep track of your position using an index, you could rename your forms with the index, so your form php/html code would look something like:

```
<form id="formAddComment-' . $index . '" action="dashboard.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

so you would end up with form elements with ids like `formAddComment-1`.

Then in your jquery you would select all the forms using the [startsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector and bind the submit event to them, thusly:

```
$('[id^="formAddComment"]').submit( function(e) {
    // do your ajax
});
```

That way each form will have it's own submit handler.

Comment: thanks man, I ran your fiddle in firebug and saw what it supposed to look like when an ajax request is made, but I get nothing of the sort when testing. Could this be because there are multiple instances of the form on the page?

Comment: i was testing on the third instance of the form, then I got the bright idea to test it on the FIRST instance of the form on the page and the ajax request was made. So, as you might guess, all the data from all the form instances was posted. How do I post only the data from the selected form in jquery?

Comment: another alternative would be not to use an `<input type="submit" />` and instead to use a `<button />` and attach a `click()` handler instead of the `submit()` handler

Answer (score 0):

In firebug, click on console, then on all.  When you click on the button to trigger your ajax call you should see a line pop up, probably with a loading icon that shows a post request being sent.  You should be able to click on the tabs to see what data is being posted and what response is given as well as a response status code...

In your edit, you say the success function will send out a new div id="comments" to replace the existing one, but as you have it written now, I believe it will just add a div id="comments" inside the existing one.  Don't know if this would cause your problem though.

Comment: OK a post showed to dashboard.php which is my forms action, shall I remove the action from my form?

Comment: thanks again, but I am pretty sure I am not getting an ajax post at this point, cause firebug showed my post routing to dashboard.php but I want it to send it to the external script comment.php.

Comment: yes I think you will have to remove/change your action attribute

Comment: OK, took out the forms action-method-enctype attributes, still nothing in firebug, so now we know it is in the jquery script, any ideas guys?

Comment: Ok. I don't really know why it wouldn't work from the code you posted.  My guess is that your function isn't actually stopping the submit event with preventDefault, since it showed a post to dashboard.php, not your ajax url and then nothing once you removed the action.  Honestly, I always have issues with preventDefault on things like form submits and links.  I usually opt for a button element instead of a submit input.  If you need a non javascript option, you can have a button and a submit, and show the appropriate one accordingly.  Sorry, that's all I've got right now

Comment: No problem kgarrigan, I think your assessment is right the preventDefault is not stopping the form submit as expected. I dunno maybe someone else will get this one.

Comment: Do you have any other forms in the same HTML document? Maybe a user login at the top of the page? If any element has a name or id of submit, it will mess with jquery .submit(). I've made that mistake before.

Comment: cori makes a good point, if you are trying to reference div_comments with jquery, you need to put $(div_comments).html(msg);

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple forms on the same page, with the same id's this will cause the problem. Especially the # formAddComment id, which is attached to the submit () call. If there are multiple of these ids, this won't work

Comment: yeah there is multiple instances of the #formAddComment id, but there has to be a way to do this, with some sort of .parent().find() selection, or am I crazy?

Comment: I have done something like this with links before to slide up and slide divs to show and collapse comments.

Comment: You are echoing this from php, right? Try adding a count,  and change id's to "formAddcomment".$ count so it's html will be "formAddcomment1", etc then go from there... Change your jquery selector for submit () to a class name and add that class to your forms... That should work. Html id's have to be unique, only once per document

Comment: Yes echoing out X(ever changing number) amount of them from a while loop. I can iterate the id's as you mentioned above, no problem, but I am still unclear on the jquery selection process you mentioned. Could you do a quick markup in an answer?